# Checking if ARGV is given when running a program with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, argv

When running a program with node:

```
node test.js
```

How do you check if the program is given an `ARGV` when run `node test.js --example`? What I've tried so far is the following:

```
function say(input){
    console.log(input);
}

if(process.argv[1] !== '')
{
    say('false');
}
else {
    say('success');
}
```

---

```
if(process.argv[1] === null)
{
    say('false');
}
else {
    say('success');
}
```

However the first solution won't output the `else` and the second solution only outputs `NUL is not defined` so with that, what I'm thinking is that I'm making some mistake in my coding?

Comment: `NUL is not defined`

Comment: @maioman Isn't `NUL` just a way to say not there?

Comment: try `(process.argv[1] === undefined)` , `NUL` isn't predefined in js

Comment: @maioman Well it works, but it doesn't output the information just exits the process

Comment: @maioman Why is `NUL` not predefined?

Comment: it should work... how are you running the program?

Comment: `node test.js` outputs nothing, but if I run `node test.js --example` it will output `success`

Comment: I think you're counting process.argv wrong ; try console.log(process.argv)

Comment: `[ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
  'C:\\Users\\thomas_j_perkins\\bin\\javascript\\node\\email\\test.js',
  '--example' ]`

Comment: NUL is not how you "say" null in JavaScript. There are two different kinds of null values in JS as well. `null` is an explicit null value, whereas `undefined` is null by lack of definition (though it can be explicitly set as well)

Comment: @BrandonAnzaldi So it's `null` and not `NUL`?

Comment: That is correct. [Docs on `null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null), [Docs on `undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) It's important to note that `null !== undefined`

Comment: @BrandonAnzaldi Awesome, thank you sir.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- argv[0] is the name of your node inerpretor --> in general node
- argv[1] is the path to your script. So argv[1] is always filled

try this to be very well aware :

```
console.log(process.argv);
```

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to the answer provided by *kevin ternet*, and for the information provided by *maioman* what I ended up doing was this:

```
if(process.argv[2] === undefined){
    say('false');
} else {
    say('true');
}
```

Here's what happens when you process `ARGV` in Node:

*`ARGV[0]`*:

```
if(process.argv[0] === undefined){
    console.log('Failure');
    console.log(process.argv[0]);

} else {
    console.log('Success');
    console.log(process.argv[0]);
}
```

Output:

```
Success
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe //Path to node executable
```

---

*`ARGV[1]`*:

```
if(process.argv[1] === undefined){
    console.log('Failure');
    console.log(process.argv[1]);

} else {
    console.log('Success');
    console.log(process.argv[1]);
}
```

Output:

```
Success
C:\Users\bin\javascript\node\test.js //Path to file
```

---

*`ARGV[2]`*:

```
if(process.argv[2] === undefined){
    console.log('Failure');
    console.log(process.argv[1]);

} else {
    console.log('Success');
    console.log(process.argv[2]);
}
```

Output:

```
Success
--example //The actual flag that was given
```

---

So therefore to check if a flag is actually given, you look for `ARGV[2]`.

Here's an example of the entire `ARGV` tree ran:

```
if(process.argv === undefined){
    console.log('Failure');
    console.log(process.argv);

} else {
    console.log('Success');
    console.log(process.argv);
}

Success
[ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe' //ARGV[0],
  'C:\\Users\\bin\\javascript\\node\\test.js' //ARGV[1],
  '--example' //ARGV[2] ]
```

So as you can see the tree is structured as an array, with the first argument being `0`.